# ADFS does not pass NameID

Tags: adfs2.0

Here is the way authentication is set up.
- Client Browser sends the request (URL below) to client's ADFS server,
- Client ADFS then look at the nested relay state and forward the request to our ADFS server.
- Our ADFS look at the request and send the request to our APP.

URL is here.

```
https://clientadfs.clientdomain.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx?RelayState=RPID%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2ouradfs.ourdomain.com%2Fadfs%2Fls%2F%26RelayState%3DRPID%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2ourapp.ourdomain.com%2Fvaruna%2Fconsole%2Fsso.aspx%3FsamISso%26lang%3Den_CA
```

The request produces a blank page with no error on the ADFS server.

I got the fiddler trace the client. Client uses users' email address to identify the users. I can see in the SAML token sent to Client's ADFS has this email address.
This SAML token goes to our ADFS server and I see the SAML response that come out of our ADFS server. This however does not have the user email address. I think that is the problem.

On our ADFS server, I have this Client's claim (on Claims Provider Trust) to handle user ID (which is their email):

Claim Rule name:  Email
Incoming Claim type:  Name ID
Incoming Name ID format:  Email
Outgoing Name ID format:  Email
Pass through all claim values.

Here is the claim in Claim Rule Language

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] == "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"]
 => issue(Type = "Email", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType);
```

On client's ADFS config, this is their email/Userid configuration:

```
IssuanceTransformRules               : @RuleTemplate = "LdapClaims"
                                       @RuleName = "Pass email"
                                       c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccou
                                       ntname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
                                        => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/20
                                       05/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"), query = ";mail;{0}", param = c.Value);
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Can anyone spot my issue? or can you suggest where I should look at?

Thanks for your help!

- RM

Answer (score 4):

"to handle user ID (which is their email)"

So is the SAML assertion an assertion for a type of email or for a type of userID? i.e. what is the assertion name for this attribute.

On the ADFS side. to transform an email claim it expects a type of "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"

**Update**

You need to transform NameId to email. NameId also has an "Incoming name ID format" which I'm guessing is "email". You need to verify this in the SAML metadata.

So your claim rule should look like:

> c:[Type ==
>   "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
>   Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"]
>   == "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"]  => issue(Type =
>   "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress",
>   Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value,
>   ValueType = c.ValueType);

**Update 1**

ADFS supports:

```
<NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</NameIDFormat>
<NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</NameIDFormat>
<NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</NameIDFormat>
```

so the format can either be emailAddress, persistent or transient.

Try the Transform rule with all three formats and see.

Also, what claims is your application getting? You can dump them out via [How to: Access Claims in an ASP.NET Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ee517271.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Client sent their ADFS config. here is their email claim config. I edited the original post above

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I thought that's how I did it. Transforming Name ID to Email. Used a "Transform an incoming claim rule". Incoming Claim type: Name ID Incoming Name ID format: Email Outgoing Name ID format: Email Pass through all claim values.

Comment: But I see you have a different "Type" in the answer. I am not able to do that using "Transform an imcoming claim rule. Should I use a custom rule?

Comment: Can you paste your actual claim rule? Not sure which "Type" is different. Also did you get which NameID format is in the SAML metadata?

Comment: Claim on my ADFS for this client is added in the original post now - in Claims language. I tried changing it to yours using a custom rule. it did not work. it produced the blank page again

Comment: Are you asking about NameID format on my ADFS server. How do I get the SAML metadata?